# Can't find Apply Force Torque plugin in gazebo garden

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

Environment:
OS: Linux Ubuntu 22.04
gazebo version: garden

Problem:
When I‘m following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/tutorials/apply_force_torque.md), I can't find Apply Force Torque plugin
[image]

Does my gazebo need update or there's something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality was only very recently merged, so probably the packages haven't been updated yet. If you can't wait for the updated packages, you can compile Gazebo from source. This is not particularly difficult, just follow [the instructions](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu_src).